# JSON.parse da error pero con eval correcto

Tags: json

Tengo

```
var data = `[
    { cod: 2, tipo: 'MAÑANA' }, 
    { cod: 4, tipo: 'NOCHE' }, 
    { cod: 3, tipo: 'TIENDAS V.O.' }
]`;
```

Al hacer el pase de json me da error:

```
var aData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Con eval va bien.

```
var data = eval(data);
```

¿Cual es el problema con el parse?

Comment: @A.Cedano data es un string, no un objeto. data[0] sería `'['`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás confundiendo la sintaxis de un objeto Javascript con JSON: JSON es una notación más estricta:

1. No se pueden usar comillas simples como delimitadores.
2. Es obligatorio poner entre comillas los nombres de los atributos (las claves).

Por tanto un JSON válido sería:

```js
var data='[{ "cod": 2, "tipo": "MAÑANA" }, { "cod": 4, "tipo": "NOCHE" }, { "cod": 3, "tipo": "TIENDAS V.O." }]';

var parsedData=JSON.parse(data);

console.log(parsedData)
```

Por cierto, te aconsejo usar las comillas simples para delimitar texto en Javascript, de ese modo podrás usar las dobles internamente sin tener que escaparlas `"\"así\""`

Comment: Gracias. Muy instructivo.